# Need to speed up jQuery for selecting options lines in multiple selection tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to speed up this jQuery line for select  tag with possilbly several thousand option tags.  Is there anything faster than the following jQuery line?  Maybe javascript? I'm even looking for a replacement b/c code is slow and unresponsive if used in conjunction with a selecttagname change event.

```
var selectedsize = $("Select[name='selecttagname'] option:selected").size();


 <select multiple name='selecttagname'>
 <option selected="selected" value="1">Aladin</option>
 <option value="2">Atlantis</option>
.... ~5000 more of these</option></select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to speed up a selector, perhaps you should rethink having ~5000 option elements on a page (eg: using jQuery UI autocomplete to search for elements from a server-side script, then populating a new list with each selected value).

Comment: Thx. Auto complete would work if I was selecting only one item.  But running into a problem with multiple selection.  I just moved my code to the form submit so it won't interfere until they perform a form submission.

Comment: If you're having problems with autocomplete, post another question :). It's definitely possible to use Autocomplete. Having 5000 elements on the page is certainly worse than tweaking autocomplete to work for you :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to start with, your selector is invalid so jQuery is manually parsing the selector AND the DOM tree to find your elements.

this is a *slight* improvement over what you have:

```
var count = $('select[name="selecttagname"]').find('option:selected').length
```

notice how I also split the selector in 2, the first part will be accelerated by browsers that support **querySelectorAll** API and simplifies the second query which is still custom and will remain slow-ish (`:selected` is a jQuery extension). This is the best you can do with just jQuery.

Now for *possibly* some extra speed you can manually query the DOM, not sure if this is gonna be faster, but you can skip the Sizzle parser for the ':selected' part.

try this:

```
var count = $('select[name="selecttagname"] option').filter(function() {
    return this.selected;
}).length;
```

In theory, this last one is faster. Let us know what are your findings after testing it.